# How can I re-arrange this regex to work with the MM/DD/YYYY format?

Tags: regex

There's a [brilliant bit of regex by Macs Dickinson](https://regexr.com/2vg48) that validates DD/MM/YYYY strings taking into account allowable days for each month (eg 28 vs 30 vs 31) and the possibility of February 29th but only on leap years:

```
^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[13578]|1[02])|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)[- /.](0[469]|11)|(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[- /.]02)[- /.]\d{4}|29[- /.]02[- /.](\d{2}(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|([02468][048]|[1359][26])00))$
```

I'm looking to re-arrange this to use for MM/DD/YYYY strings, but I can't wrap my head around it enough to get it there. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I must ask: why?

Comment: You failed to tag the language. You got the regex tag down at least.

Comment: Don't you just need to swap the parts of the regexp around the first `[- / .]`?

Comment: @RubensFarias `MM/DD/YYYY` is how dates are commonly written in the US.

Comment: @Barmar, my point is: most programming languages do have a `Date` data type; is regex the right tool for this job?

Comment: @RubensFarias Before you can call the date functions you have to find the date in the input text, and a regexp is useful for that.

Comment: @RubensFarias - I thought most macro languages provide epoch functions.Like whats the epoch for a particular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you posted has a mistake in the *Leap Year* section.
Otherwise it is a fair facsimile of that form.

I've fixed his mistake, and rearranged the day/month for you.
It now matches *MM/DD/YYYY*.

`((?:0[13578]|1[02])[- /.](?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(?:0[469]|11)[- /.](?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|02[- /.](?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))[- /.](\d{4})|(02[- /.]29)[- /.]([0-9]{2}(?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00)`

Formatted / explained

```
   (                                            # (1 start), Non-LeapYr  MM/DD
        (?: 0 [13578] | 1 [02] )                     # Months with 31 days
        [- /.] 
        (?: 0 [1-9] | [12] [0-9] | 3 [01] )
     |  
        (?: 0 [469] | 11 )                           # Months with 30 days
        [- /.] 
        (?: 0 [1-9] | [12] [0-9] | 30 )
     |  
        02                                           # February with 28 days
        [- /.] 
        (?: 0 [1-9] | 1 \d | 2 [0-8] )
   )                                            # (1 end)
   [- /.] 
   ( \d{4} )                                    # (2), Any year 0000 - 9999

|                                             # OR, 

   ( 02 [- /.] 29 )                             # (3), LeapYear  MM/DD
   [- /.] 
   (                                            # (4 start), Leap Years 0000 - 9996
        [0-9]{2} 
        (?: 0 [48] | [13579] [26] | [2468] [048] )
     |  
        (?: [02468] [048] | [13579] [26] )
        00
   )                                            # (4 end)
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it works perfectly. What was the mistake with leap years in the original regex?

Comment: You're welcome! The mistake was `[1359]` should be `[13579]`. There is a leap year tool here [www.regexformat.com](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn8/LY_1.jpg). He was trying to do the range 0000-9996 which is `([0-9]{2}(?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00)` So, his would miss leap years 7200,  7600, etc..